# http sending nulls in PUT Request (Angular + spring jpa app)

Tags: javascript, angular, spring, api, postman

so ive a simple spring jpa rest app with angular. My api deployed in heroku has an structure similar like this:

> [{"id":1,"name":"jose","surname":"garcia","dni":"","address":"","mail":"eve.holt@reqres.in","phone":"650264663","linkedln":"ojskdfofwa","state":"","rating":"","availability":"","tags":[{"id":1,"name":"php"},{"id":1,"name":"php"}

So id like to allow users to add tags in user tag field. Im using a PUT request for this that send entire form of user in req body with news tags added.

this is how i take new tags with reactiveform and push to expert:

**expertdetail.ts:**

```
  constructor( private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private router: Router, private expertService: ExpertsService) {this.expert= this.router?.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.expert;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      tags: this.formBuilder.array([])

    });



  }
  get tagsArray(): FormArray{
    return this.formGroup.get('tags') as FormArray
  }

  addTag() {

    const tags = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(2)])]
      }
    );
    this.tagsArray.push(tags);
     
     this.expert.tags.push(this.formGroup.value)
     this.expertService.updateExpert(this.expert).subscribe((response) => {
      if(response){
       alert('etiqueta añadida con exito');
       }else{
        alert('Error: No Token Received');
      }
     }


     )}
```

the console.log of expert seems ok,In red are the tags that user already has. In blue what I try to insert:

[image]

My method to update in expert-service:

```
 updateExpert(expert){
    return this.http.put('https://serene-wave-12377.herokuapp.com/api/experts', expert);
```

The call returns an OK response, but then when I go to my API I see this:

> [{"id":1,"name":"jose","surname":"garcia","dni":"","address":"","mail":"eve.holt@reqres.in","phone":"650264663","linkedln":"","state":"","rating":"","availability":"","tags":[{"id":1,"name":"php"},{"id":1,"name":"php"},{"id":1,"name":"php"},{"id":1,"name":"php"},{"id":2,"name":"c++"},{"id":2,"name":"c++"},{"id":2,"name":"c++"},{"id":2,"name":"c++"},{"id":3,"name":null},{"id":4,"name":null},{"id":5,"name":null},{"id":6,"name":null},{"id":7,"name":null},{"id":8,"name":null}]}]

It seems like it's adding tags and generating more IDS, but name is null.

In my Spring JPA I update like this:

```
    public Expert updateExpert(Expert expert) {
        Expert updatedExpert = manager.find(Expert.class, expert.getId());
        updatedExpert.setName(expert.getName());
        updatedExpert.setMail(expert.getMail());
        updatedExpert.setSurname(expert.getSurname());
        updatedExpert.setPhone(expert.getPhone());
        updatedExpert.setAvailability(expert.getAvailability());
        updatedExpert.setAddress(expert.getAddress());
        updatedExpert.setDni(expert.getDni());
        updatedExpert.setLinkedln(expert.getLinkedln());
        updatedExpert.setRating(expert.getRating());
        updatedExpert.setState(expert.getState());
        updatedExpert.getTags().addAll(expert.getTags());
        manager.merge(updatedExpert);
        return updatedExpert;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have some idea? I've tried more combinations but nothing seems to work. I've tried with Postman and it also inserts null values always. Expert and tags have a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Please share your Expert and Tag classes. This might be because of improper models

Answer (score 0):

this are my expert and tag models. All fields are inserted OK except tags field

**expert model:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="experts")
public class Expert {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String dni;
    private String address;
    private String mail;
    private String phone;
    private String linkedln;
    private String state;
    private String rating;
    private String availability;



    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "experts_tags",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="tags_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="experts_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();


    public Expert() {
    }

    public Expert(String name, String surname, String dni, String address, String mail, String phone, String linkedln, String state, String rating, List<Tag> tags, String availability) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.dni = dni;
        this.address = address;
        this.mail = mail;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.linkedln = linkedln;
        this.state = state;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.tags = tags;
        this.availability = availability;
    } //getters and setters
```

**tag model:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tags")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="tags")
    private List<Expert> experts = new ArrayList<>();

    public Tag() {
    }  //getters and setters
```